# Bootstrap dropdown is not working or is not toggling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. Please tell me what is wrong with this code since I cannot seem to make my dropdown or the toggle work. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Red Stone One Stop Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css " />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scaleable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">  
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/ecommerce/index.php" class="navbar-brand">Red Stone One Stop Shop</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Dropdown menu -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is get the official [Boiler Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) from bootstrap website. That will make things easier. And do the changes as you desire.

See the example below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Red Stone One Stop Shop</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          <a href="/ecommerce/index.php" class="navbar-brand">Red Stone One Stop Shop</a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <!-- Dropdown menu -->
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="text">Men  <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the working example: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bologutico/1/edit?html,output)

---

**But the issue in your code is that your jquery version is old, just update it to a version like**, `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js`. Because I believe you are using bootstrap version 3.x.x

See the working example after updating the jquery version: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xebiqihori/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

I've done your example in JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ginibamimi/edit?html,output) and it works correctly.

It seems that the version of jQuery you were using was too old for it.

Change this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
```

for this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes charly, I tried it in JSFiddle and it works.I update the jquery.min.js as Jerad suggested and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: so what was wrong in comparison to the original example asked in the question itself, can you elaborate?

Comment: You are right Toby sorry for this. I edit my answer so!

Answer (score 0):

Check if bootstrap css is added in head tag.
If not, add this to the head tag in the html.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```